# Plotly Dash: Conditionally changing datatable cell color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I've got the following code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['col1', 'col2'],
    data=[
        ['aaaa', 5],
        ['aa', 6],
        ['bbbb', 7],
        ['cccc',8]

    ]

)
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

styles = [{'if': {
                        'column_id': 'col1',
                        'filter_query': '{col1} contains {val}'
                    },
                    'backgroundColor': background_color,
                    'color': 'white'
                } for val, background_color in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                            ['#FF0000', "#00FF00", '#0000FF'])]

app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        style_cell={'font-family':'sans-serif'},
        style_data_conditional=styles
)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I'm trying to change the background color of the `col1` column if it contains a, b or c. I know that I need to use style_data_conditional, but can't figure out how to reference the column name correctly. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the filter query in your code is that `val` is a string and is therefore not being updated based on the values in the list (i.e. it is always equal to `'val'` instead of taking the values `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`). If you replace `val` with a variable as in the example below your code should work as expected.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['col1', 'col2'],
    data=[['aaaa', 5],
          ['aa',   6],
          ['bbbb', 7],
          ['cccc', 8]]
)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

styles = [{'if': {'column_id': 'col1', 'filter_query': '{col1} contains ' + val},
'backgroundColor': background_color, 'color': 'white'} for val, background_color
in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['#FF0000', "#00FF00", '#0000FF'])]

app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        style_cell={'font-family': 'sans-serif'},
        style_data_conditional=styles
)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1')
```

[image]